# How to Get Collection inside document in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my React app with version 17, I integrated Firebase v9.6.6.

I have one collection. Inside that collection, I have documents, and within each document, there are additional collections.

Now, I want to obtain a list of those collections in an array.

How can I achieve this? I want a highlighted list, as shown in the image:

[image]

I tried this:

```
export const getCollectionsList = async () => {
  const docRef = collection(db, 'openings');
  console.log('docRef: ', docRef);
  const openingSnapshot = doc(docRef, 'White Opening Data');
  const openingData = openingSnapshot?.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data()
  }));
  console.log('openingData: ', openingData);
};
```

I want a list of that collections, because I want to display those collection names in my app. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Getting data from a subcollection is quite well documented (with code samples) here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_subcollection. Can you show what you tried already, and what isn't working about it?

Comment: ```
export const getCollectionsList = async () => {
  const docRef = collection(db, 'openings');
  console.log('docRef: ', docRef);
  const openingSnapshot = doc(docRef, 'White Opening Data');

  const openingData = openingSnapshot?.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data()
  }));
  console.log('openingData: ', openingData);
};
```


I tried this @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want a list of that collections so can you help me with this?
Because I want to display those collection names in my app.

Comment: The client-side SDKs have no way to get a list of collections. The list of collections has to be known ahead of time, or you'll need to store it in a document and read it from there.

Comment: how can I do that in nextJS?

can you help ? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: This will require more than just a code-change, which is beyond what we can reasonably cover in an answer. The answer to the second question I linked pretty much enumerates all your options though. I recommend picking one (typically, storing the collection names in a doc is my first step) and trying to make that work. If you run into specific problems while implementing that, I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).